# Replace found comma separated items with space separated items using regex

Tags: regex, replace

**My Problem**

I have a large XML file in which someone mistakenly separated some space-separated identifiers with commas in an attribute.  There are far too many instances to fix this by hand, so I wanted to do a regex replace.

I can do a non-greedy match of the "i" attribute, but I'm not sure how to do the non-greedy match and combine it with a string replace of comma-to-space.

**Non-Greedy Match Regex**

```
i="(.*?)"
```

**Sample Data**

```
<c id="group_1">
    <i id="item_1" i="F:41 F:42 F:D4 G:H3">
        <id="tag_1" />
    </i>
    <i id="item_2" i="R:08,F:42,F:D8,G:H23">
        <id="tag_2" />
    </i>
</c>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Actually, the IntelliJ IDE has pretty powerful regex support that I'm using.  It highlights all matches as you type the regex and shows you what it would replace each with when you use the captures.  It seems to follow java regex though if I had to guess.  I can happily use PERL or whatever you like though if you have a solution; it's a one off :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/cW2dM3/1)

**Find Regex**

```
([^,]+)(,)?
```

**Replace Regex**

```
\1
```

***Note***: There is a space in the replace regex.

Comment: This works pretty well.  I just have to modify it with negative lookbehind or something similar to stop it from replacing commas in other parts of the data.  Thanks :).